# My session is getting destroyed after a post request

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Background: I am making a HubSpot app so I must use an IFrame to render a function of my app. All goes well until I need to access a session variable I previously made. I am using ngrok to point to my local environment because I need to use an HTTPS connection. I made the code simpler just to test this behavior but I had no luck in finding my problem.

```
session_start([
    "use_strict_mode" => true,
    "use_only_cookies" => true,
    "use_trans_sid" => false
]);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'sas';
    error_log("GET:" . json_encode($_SESSION));
?>
    <form method="POST">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </form>
<?php
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
    error_log("POST:" . json_encode($_SESSION));
}
```

This is the entire file. On the first error_log I get: GET:{"test":"sas"} but when I submit my form I get: POST:[]

Comment: Is there any other code in the script or this all of it?

Comment: This is all of it. I intentionally made it simple just to make sure I did not miss anything